# Running swift 3 script

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, command-line, xcode9

We have an app written in Swift 3.2 but we want to use Xcode 9. This works fine but we have a Run Script Phase that runs a Swift script that is also written in Swift 3.

Testing on the command line we tried using `-swift-version 3` but are getting conflicting errors around the input file:

```sh
$ swift -swift-version 3 Script.swift
Missing required options: ["-i, --input"]

Usage: Script.swift [options]
  -i, --input:
      Required | String | Path to the localization file
  -o, --outpu:
      Optional | String | Path to output file (.swift or .m, depending on your configuration. If you are using ObjC, header will be created on that location. If ommited, output will be sent to stdout instead.
  -l, --langu:
      Optional | String | [swift | objc] | Specifies language of generated output files | Defaults to [swift]
  -d, --delim:
      Optional | String | String delimiter to separate segments of each string | Defaults to [.]
  -c, --capit:
      Optional | Bool | When enabled, name of all structures / methods / properties are automatically CamelCased | Defaults to false
  -b, --baseC:
      Optional | String | Name of the base class | Defaults to "Localizations"
  -t, --strin:
      Optional | String | Name of strings table | Defaults to nil
  -s, --custo:
      Optional | String | A custom superclass name | Defaults to NSObject (only applicable in ObjC)
$ swift -swift-version 3 -i Script.swift
<unknown>:0: error: the flag '-i' is no longer required and has been removed; use 'swift input-filename'
$ swift -swift-version 3 --input Script.swift
<unknown>:0: error: unknown argument: '--input'
```

Not sure why this is happening. This is using Xcode 9 GM seed.